# is it possible to restore DB to azure sql from backup file's url using an Azure API?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

i'm reading about doing the restore to azure sql using azure management studio using T-SQL queries:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj852091.aspx

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 
FROM URL = 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/privatecontainertest/AdventureWorks2012.bak' 
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'mycredential';
, STATS = 5 – use this to see monitor the progress
GO
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically using an azure API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Azure REST API to restore. The following link shows the ways to restore a deleted database:

[Restore Deleted Database Tutorial through REST](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-restore-deleted-database-tutorial-rest/)

You can build and send a POST request to the following URL with your subscription ID and server name.

```
https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{subscriptionId}/services/sqlservers/servers/{serverName}/restoredatabaseoperations
```

Cheers, 
Luis

Comment: thank you for the response, unfortunately this is not exactly what i mean by  restore. I mean, I want to know how to restore to azure sql by starting with a backup file of an entire database (bak or bakpac)

Comment: I'm looking for this as well, but perhaps the SQL statement is enough for now.

Comment: The suggestion in the topic will not work... Msg 40510, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Statement 'RESTORE DATABASE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.